# Problems to tween the transparency of threejs plane and css3d objects

Tags: three.js, gsap

I create the objects like shown below:

```
var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
element.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-5x"></i>';
object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
object.position.set(11,4,8)
object.name = "error"
object.transparent = true;
object.scale.set(0.01,0.01,0.01)

SceneService.sceneCss.add(object);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
   color: 0xFF0101,
   side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.copy(object.position);
mesh.rotation.copy(object.rotation);
mesh.scale.copy(object.scale);
mesh.transparent = true;
mesh.name = "error_plane"
SceneService.scene.add(mesh);
```

I have set the transparent property. The I try to hide the "error plane"

```
object = SceneService.scene.getObjectByName('error_plane');
tweens.push(tl.to(object.material, 5, {opacity: 0}, 0));
```

But it did not work. The css3d object did not have any material. Any ideas how I can tween the opacity?

Comment: can you prepare a simple fiddle demonstrating the problem please?

Answer (score 2):

You can tween the opacity of a `CSS3DObject` using a pattern like so:

```
var current = {
    opacity: 1
};

new TWEEN.Tween( current )
    .to( { opacity: 0 }, 2000 )
    .onUpdate( function () {
        object.element.style.opacity = current.opacity;
    } )
    .start();
```

Then, in the animation loop, call

```
TWEEN.update();
```

You can tween the opacity of a `Mesh` object using a pattern like this one:

```
var current = {
    opacity: 1
};

new TWEEN.Tween( current )
    .to( { opacity: 0 }, 2000 )
    .onUpdate( function () {
        object.material.opacity = current.opacity;
    } )
    .start();
}
```

You must set `object.material.transparent = true;` for the 2nd pattern to work. You must also call `TWEEN.update();` in the animation loop.

three.js r.72

Comment: tweens.push(tl.to(object.element, 5, {opacity: 0}, 5)); this works for css3D objects. now I only need a solution for the plane

Comment: Updated answer. Make sure in your demo you set `mesh.material.transparent = true`.