# How to add a transition when changing the displacementScale of the displacementMap in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, maps

I'm experimenting with three.js maps. The thing is, I created a function to update the `displacementScale` randomly. But, the problem is that when it's updated, it changes instantly without transition. Is there a way to add a transition?

code:

```
const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10, 65, 65)
const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 'gray',
    map: texture,
    displacementMap: clouds,
    displacementScale: 1.5,
    // adding alpha map to remove hard edges
    alphaMap: alpha,
    transparent: true,
    depthTest: false,
})
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMaterial)
scene.add(planeMesh)
planeMesh.rotation.x = 200

const animateDisplacementMap = () => {
    planeMesh.material.displacementScale = .3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 550) * .003

    setTimeout(() => {
        animateDisplacementMap()
    }, 1000);
}
animateDisplacementMap()

const animate = () => {
    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()
```

example:

[image]

Comment: Try tween - similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/32720610/1461008

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work there's no transition still :(